# Apache Ignite - SQL Support for HashMaps?

Tags: java, hashmap, ignite

Hi there I like to use at Apache Ignite a Pojo which has a HashMap attribute so I can work with dynamic models at runtime. Storing and Saving of such objects works fine.

However, I m wondering if there a way exist to access the key / values of such a Hashmap through a SQL query? If this is not supported any other ways I can work in Apache Ignite with dynamic objects?

**POJO Class with dynamic attributes**

```
@Data
public class Item {
    
    private static final AtomicLong ID_GEN = new AtomicLong();

    @QuerySqlField(index = true)
    private Long id;
    
    @QuerySqlField
    public Map<String,Serializable> attributes = new HashMap<String,Serializable>();

    public Item(Long id, String code, String name) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    
    public Item() {
        this(ID_GEN.incrementAndGet());
    }
    
    public void setAttribute(String name,Serializable value) {
        attributes.put(name, value);
    }

    public Serializable getAttribute(String name) {
        return attributes.get(name);
    }
}
```

**Example Query Feature illstrated**

```
SqlFieldsQuery query = new SqlFieldsQuery("SELECT * FROM Item WHERE attributes('Price') > 100");
```

Comment: ignite is already a big hashmap, then you want to add another hashmap into it?

Comment: Yes because my data model the objects I like to store have dynamic members

Comment: I am asking because my impression from ignite is that it's just another type of hashmap in memory storage, just like elasticsearch, so the "SQL" way of querying things is just a syntax sugar around the tradictional noSQL way of querying things, which is probably as simple as possible, so I would not expect many features or a great performance from it.

Answer (score 1):

SQL in Ignite is not just syntactic sugar, it requires a schema of your models to be defined before you can run SQL queries and this won't work for a collection. Therefore you need to normalize the data just like with a regular DB or rework the model's structure somehow to avoid JOIN.

Answer (score 1):

Apache Ignite has no support for destructuring/collections in its SQL, so you can't peek inside HashMap via SQL.

However, you may define [your own SQL functions](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/SQL/custom-sql-func), so you can implement e.g. `SELECT hashmap_get(ATTRIBUTES, 'subkey') FROM ITEM WHERE ID = ?`

But you can't have indexes on function application so the usefulness is limited.